# Hive - Insert data into partitioned table: partition not found

Tags: hadoop, insert, hive

I'm having issue while trying to inserting new data in Hive external partitioned table.

Table is partitioned by day, the error I got is:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10006]: Line 1:51 Partition not found ''18102016''
```

My query is as following:

```
ALTER TABLE my_source_table RECOVER PARTITIONS;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_dest_table PARTITION (d = '18102016')
SELECT
  'III' AS primary_alias_type,
   iii_id AS primary_alias_id,
FROM
   my_source_table
WHERE 
   d = '18102016'
```

The  *my_dest_table* has been created as:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_dest_table (
   primary_alias_type string,
   primary_alias_id
) PARTITIONED BY (d string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 's3://my_bucket/my_external_tables/'
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: probably not the issue, but you have an extra comma after `primary_alias_id `

Comment: Was this problem solved ? I am having exact same issue

Comment: @Confused yes it was, through the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should `ALTER TABLE my_source_table RECOVER PARTITIONS;` do this for your destination table.

```
ALTER TABLE my_dest_table RECOVER PARTITIONS;
```

try this.

Note: Of course you should remove the extra comma what Alex L mentioned. Which will give other parsing error.